# Make jQuery plugin method publicly available once the plugin has been applied to an element

Tags: jquery, extend, public-method

I'm modifying an existing jQuery plugin that currently has a private function (assigned to a var within the plugin scope) that I would like to expose so I can call it from outside the plugin at an arbitrary time (in response to a UI event, for example).

Essentially, I would like the following to work:

```
$('.foo').myPlugin();
```

... and later (perhaps within an event callback):

```
$('.foo').publicMethodInsidePlugin();
```

or even:

```
$('.foo').myPlugin.publicMethodInsidePlugin();
```

I understand that jQueryUI has an alternate approach, but I was hoping to avoid that and keep it simple.

### UPDATE

The reason I *believe* is the challenge for this plugin is that the "private" function I'm trying to call is defined within the `return this.each(function(){})` portion of the plugin. It would be very hard to pull this function out, because it depends on a number of variables that, themselves, are defined as private vars inside the scope of the `this.each` block, presumably because the values might be different for each element on which the function is applied.

### Basic Structure

The basic structure of said plugin is:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        var settings = { "variousDefaults" : true }

        return this.each(function(){
            if(options) {
                    $.extend(settings, options);
            };

            var $this               = $(this),
                someOtherVars       = $("span", $this).length; // needs to evaluate on $this

            privateFunc = function privateFunc() {
              // the function that I want to be able to call after the fact...
            };

            // Immediately call that function
            privateFunc();

            $(window).resize(function() {
                privateFunc();
            });
         });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

How do I refactor this such that I can call privateFunc after the fact? I'm open to creating another, public function that then calls this function, if that means less refactoring.

Comment: Yes, if your plugin is created in such a way that it returns an instance of a class per element, store that instance on the element's data and reference it there. `$(elem).data("myPlugin",theInstance)` To give a complete answer, we'd need to see how the plugin is defined.

Comment: @KevinB that worked well. I just stored the private function as the data element. Still, there must be a better way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

The "jQuery" way is to use the plugin constructor to call different methods, like an API of sorts:

```
$('.foo').myPlugin();
$('.foo').myPlugin('someMethod', ['arg1', 'arg2']);
```

Another way I've seen it done is to store the API in the object's data store:

```
$('.foo').myPlugin();
$('.foo').data('myPluginAPI').someMethod('arg1', 'arg2');
```

Comment: I like the looks of your first option, but I wonder is that only valid when you first call the plugin on the element? I mean, in your first example, supposing the plugin is doing some computationally-heavy stuff when you run .myPlugin(), will it run again when you do .myPlugin('someMethod')?

Comment: You would track the initialization status in the data store, i.e. `$(this).data('myPluginInitialized', true)`